# Jdbc multiple delete

Tags: java, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I need to make a multiple delete with parameters.I know that exists [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#addBatch%28java.lang.String%29) method on Statement but it is without parameters.
And [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#batchUpdate%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) it's the same(no parameters).

How can i make this in a single call to database:

`delete from table1 where id_table1=:id_table1`

`delete from table2 where id_table2=:id_table2`

`delete from table3 where id_table3=:id_table3`

Comment: Why is it a problem to make several calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my opinion use multiple delete statements within a transaction or use triggers to do the cascading deletes or submit a batch as follows:

Comment: Ok, if it is not possible.With this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#addBatch%28java.lang.String%29 i can make a multiple delete:addBatch("delete from table1 where id_table1="+id_table1);addBatch("delete from table2 where id_table2="+id_table2),but it's not what I want.

Comment: Here it's not possible, as your delete statements are not same

Answer (score 3):

You can't since your DELETE statements are not the same. If you were deleting from the same table you could either have a more complex WHERE condition or create a batch with a `PreparedStatement`; but here it's not possible.